# Scheduling update functions in Django and Heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku, celery

I am working on a project, to be deployed on Heroku in Django, which has around 12 update functions. They take around 15 minutes to run each. Let's call them update1(), update2()...update10().

I am deploying with one worker dyno on Heroku, and I would like to run up to n or more of these at once (They are not really computationally intensive, they are all HTML parsers, but the data is time-sensitive, so I would like them to be called as often as possible).

I've read a lot of Celery and APScheduler documentation, but I'm not really sure which is the best/easiest for me. Do scheduled tasks run concurrently if the times overlap with one another (ie. if I run one every 2 minutes, and another every 3 minutes, or do they wait until each one finishes?)

Any way I can queue these functions, so at least a few of them are running at once? What is the suggested number of simultaneous calls for this use-case?

Answer (score 0):

Based on you use case description you do not need a Scheduler, so APScheduler will not match your requirements well.

Do you have a web dyno besides your worker dyno? The usual design pattern for this type of processing is to set up a control thread or control process (your web dyno) that accepts requests. These requests are then placed on a request queue.

This queue is read by one or more worker threads or worker processes (you worker dyno). I have not worked with Celery, but it looks like a match with your requirements. How many worker threads or worker dyno's you will need is difficult to determine based on your description. You will need to specify also how many requests for updates you will need to process per second. Also, you will need to specify if the request is CPU bound or IO bound.